# remote ssh enable pseudo-tty allocation

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I finished the configuration of vscode **remote-ssh** extension, I got these logs as follows:

```
[19:02:36.743] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[19:02:36.766] > OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3

[19:02:36.771] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 64497 -o ConnectTimeout=15 'vscode_test' bash
[19:02:37.199] > 8474f269cd9b: running
```

Actually, I'm trying to connect the remote host using ssh without "-T", means using pseudo-tty. But I don't know how?

Comment: Are you trying to execute some command over SSH with the help of this extension?

Comment: No. I'm sorry. I didn't make myself clear and will update this post later.

Comment: Not possible with this extension, check this out -- [Error: No command or PTY requested](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/5336)

Answer (score -1):

If you enable `RequestTTY force` in your `.ssh/config` under your host, that will override the `-T`.